# Recursive Copy Of Sub-Directories Fails Using FTPS (Possible Handshake Issue?)

Tags: java, apache, recursion, ftp, ftps

I am trying to use FTPS to copy all sub-directories and files under a given directory from an FTP server to a local machine.  The program I've written gets some of the sub-directories and files before bombing.  Each time the program bombs is not always in the same place.  The code and errors I am getting are below.  Any ideas on how to get this to work?

```
import org.apache.commons.net.PrintCommandListener;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPConnectionClosedException;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPReply;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient;

public class SaigFileBuilder {

    private String server = "host";
    private String username = "user";
    private String password = "pass";
    private String remoteParentDir = "/prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/";
    private String filesep = System.getProperty("file.separator");
    private String local = "c:" + filesep + "temp" + filesep + "saig_files";
    private List<String> fileList = null;

    private boolean error = false;
    private String protocol = "TLS";  // SSL/TLS
    private FTPSClient ftps = null;



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SaigFileBuilder fb = new SaigFileBuilder();

        try {
            fb.getClientConnection();            
            fb.getFiles(false);
            fb.logout();

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.exit(fb.error ? 1 : 0);
    }



    private void getClientConnection() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {

        this.ftps = new FTPSClient(this.protocol);
        this.ftps.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out)));

        this.ftps = getConnection(server);
        this.ftps = getLogin(username, password);
    }

    private FTPSClient getConnection(String server) {

        try
        {
            int reply;

            // Connect to the FTP server...
            this.ftps.connect(server);
            System.out.println("Connected to " + server + ".");

            // Get connect reply code...
            reply = this.ftps.getReplyCode();
            System.out.println("String reply: " + this.ftps.getReplyString());

            // Verify successful connection reply code was returned...
            if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply))
            {
                error = true;
                System.err.println("FTP server refused connection.");
                return null;
            }

            // FileZilla client issues following, so I will too..
            this.ftps.sendCommand("OPTS UTF8 ON");
            this.ftps.execPBSZ(0);
            this.ftps.execPROT("P");
            this.ftps.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.err.println("Could not connect to server.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return this.ftps;    
    }


    private FTPSClient getLogin(String username, String password) {

        try
        {
            this.ftps.setBufferSize(1000);

            if (!this.ftps.login(username, password))
            {
                System.out.println("Login failed");
                this.ftps.logout();
                return null;
            }

            System.out.println("Remote system is " + this.ftps.getSystemType());

        }
        catch (FTPConnectionClosedException e)
        {
            error = true;
            System.err.println("Server closed connection.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            error = true;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return this.ftps;
    }



    private void getFiles(boolean binaryTransfer) {
        try
        {
            if (binaryTransfer) { 
                this.ftps.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            }

            OutputStream output = null;

            this.ftps.changeWorkingDirectory(this.remoteParentDir);
            System.out.println("pwd: " + this.ftps.printWorkingDirectory());

            this.fileList = new ArrayList<String>();
            scanDirTree(this.remoteParentDir);

            System.out.println("Finished scanning...");
            for (String file : this.fileList) {
            System.out.println(file);
            }

            String dirHold = " ";
            String winDir = " ";
            String winFile = " ";

            for (String ftpFilePath : this.fileList) {
                // Going to copy the remote dirs and files to local, so change the paths to 
                // use local Windows file separator instead of remote Unix... 
                winDir = ftpFilePath.substring(0, ftpFilePath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1).replace("/", filesep);
                winFile = ftpFilePath.substring(ftpFilePath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, ftpFilePath.length());
                System.out.println("winDir.: " + winDir);
                System.out.println("winFile: " + winFile);

                // If new dir found in list, then create it locally...
                if (dirHold.equals(winDir) == false) {
                    System.out.println("mkdir: " + local + winDir);
                    new File(local + winDir).mkdirs();
                    dirHold = winDir;
                }

                // And write the file locally...
                System.out.println("Attempting to write: " + this.local + winDir + winFile);
                output = new FileOutputStream(local + winDir + winFile);
                this.ftps.retrieveFile(ftpFilePath, output);

                output.close();
                output = null;
            }

        }
        catch (FTPConnectionClosedException e)
        {
            error = true;
            System.err.println("Server closed connection.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            error = true;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private void scanDirTree(String directory) throws IOException {
        // Create and return a list of all dirs and files on remote 
        // server below the parent dir that was passed to this method...
        FTPFile[] files = this.ftps.listFiles(directory);

        if (files.length == 0) {
            System.out.println("no files in " + directory);
        }

        for (FTPFile file : files) {
            String name = file.getName();


            if (!".".equals(name) && !"..".equals(name)) {
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    // Recursive call, go deeper...
                    scanDirTree(directory + name + "/");
                } else {
                    fileList.add(directory + file.getName());
                    System.out.println("Added: " + directory + file.getName());
                }
            }
        }
    }



    private void logout() {

        if (this.ftps.isConnected()) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Logging out...");
                this.ftps.logout();
                System.out.println("Disconnecting...");
                this.ftps.disconnect();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                error = true;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the error:

```
220 (vsFTPd 2.0.5)
AUTH TLS
234 Proceed with negotiation.
Connected to xxx.xxx.xxx
String reply: 234 Proceed with negotiation.

OPTS UTF8 ON
200 Always in UTF8 mode.
PBSZ 0
200 PBSZ set to 0.
PROT P
200 PROT now Private.
USER xxx
331 Please specify the password.
PASS xxxx
230 Login successful.
SYST
215 UNIX Type: L8
Remote system is UNIX Type: L8
CWD /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/
250 Directory successfully changed.
PWD
257 "/prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG"
pwd: /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (xx,xx,xxx,x,197,29)
LIST /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/
150 Here comes the directory listing.
226 Directory send OK.
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (xx,xx,xxx,x,197,46)
LIST /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/
150 Here comes the directory listing.
226 Directory send OK.
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (xx,xx,xxx,x,197,150)
LIST /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/DirectLoan/
150 Here comes the directory listing.
226 Directory send OK.
Added: /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/DirectLoan/CRDL12IN-G.xml
Added: /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/DirectLoan/CRDL12IN-GCHG.xml
Added: /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/DirectLoan/CRDL12IN-GDISB.xml
Added: /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/DirectLoan/CRDL12IN-U.xml
Added: /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/DirectLoan/CRDL12IN-UCHG.xml
Added: /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/DirectLoan/CRDL12IN-UDISB.xml
Added: /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/DirectLoan/CRDL12IN.xml
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (xx,xx,xxx,x,196,232)
LIST /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/Isir/
150 Here comes the directory listing.
226 Directory send OK.
no files in /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/Isir/
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (xx,xx,xxx,x,196,254)
LIST /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/Pell/
150 Here comes the directory listing.
226 Directory send OK.
Added: /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/Pell/CRPG12IN.xml
Added: /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/Pell/CRPG12IN_DISB.xml
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (xx,xx,xxx,x,197,5)
LIST /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/Teach/
150 Here comes the directory listing.
226 Directory send OK.
no files in /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/Teach/
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (xx,xx,xxx,x,197,66)
LIST /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/TrnsMonitor/
150 Here comes the directory listing.
226 Directory send OK.
Added: /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/TrnsMonitor/TRNINFIN.01
Added: /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/TrnsMonitor/TRNINFIN.02
Added: /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/TrnsMonitor/TRNINFIN.03
Added: /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/TrnsMonitor/TRNINFIN.04
Added: /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/TrnsMonitor/TRNINFIN.05
Added: /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/TrnsMonitor/TRNINFIN.06
Added: /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/TrnsMonitor/TRNINFIN.07
Added: /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/TrnsMonitorTRNINFIN.01
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (xx,xx,xxx,x,197,3)
LIST /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2013/
150 Here comes the directory listing.
226 Directory send OK.
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (xx,xx,xxx,x,196,230)
LIST /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2013/CommRec/
150 Here comes the directory listing.
226 Directory send OK.
no files in /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2013/CommRec/
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (xx,xx,xxx,x,197,135)
LIST /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2013/DLReconciliation/
150 Here comes the directory listing.
226 Directory send OK.
no files in /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2013/DLReconciliation/
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (xx,xx,xxx,x,197,124)
LIST /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2013/DirectLoan/
150 Here comes the directory listing.
226 Directory send OK.
Added: /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2013/DirectLoan/CRDL13IN-G.xml
Added: /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2013/DirectLoan/CRDL13IN-GCHG.xml
Added: /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2013/DirectLoan/CRDL13IN-GDISB.xml
Added: /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2013/DirectLoan/CRDL13IN-U.xml
Added: /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2013/DirectLoan/CRDL13IN-UCHG.xml
Added: /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2013/DirectLoan/CRDL13IN-UDISB.xml
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (xx,xx,xxx,x,197,121)
LIST /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2013/Isir/
150 Here comes the directory listing.
226 Directory send OK.
Added: /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2013/Isir/CORR13IN.001
Added: /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2013/Isir/CORR13IN.002
Added: /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2013/Isir/CORR13IN.003
Added: /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2013/Isir/CORR13IN.004
Added: /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2013/Isir/CORR13IN.005
Added: /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2013/Isir/CORR13IN.006
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (xx,xx,xxx,x,197,147)
LIST /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2013/Pell/
150 Here comes the directory listing.
226 Directory send OK.
Added: /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2013/Pell/CRPG13IN.xml
Added: /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2013/Pell/CRPG13IN_DISB.xml
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (xx,xx,xxx,x,197,63)
LIST /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2013/SysGen/
150 Here comes the directory listing.
226 Directory send OK.
no files in /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2013/SysGen/
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (xx,xx,xxx,x,197,118)
LIST /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2013/TrnsMonitor/
150 Here comes the directory listing.
226 Directory send OK.
Added: /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2013/TrnsMonitor/TRNINFIN.01
Finished scanning...
/prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/DirectLoan/CRDL12IN-G.xml
/prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/DirectLoan/CRDL12IN-GCHG.xml
/prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/DirectLoan/CRDL12IN-GDISB.xml
/prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/DirectLoan/CRDL12IN-U.xml
/prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/DirectLoan/CRDL12IN-UCHG.xml
/prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/DirectLoan/CRDL12IN-UDISB.xml
/prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/DirectLoan/CRDL12IN.xml
/prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/Pell/CRPG12IN.xml
/prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/Pell/CRPG12IN_DISB.xml
/prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/TrnsMonitor/TRNINFIN.01
/prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/TrnsMonitor/TRNINFIN.02
/prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/TrnsMonitor/TRNINFIN.03
/prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/TrnsMonitor/TRNINFIN.04
/prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/TrnsMonitor/TRNINFIN.05
/prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/TrnsMonitor/TRNINFIN.06
/prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/TrnsMonitor/TRNINFIN.07
/prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/TrnsMonitorTRNINFIN.01
/prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2013/DirectLoan/CRDL13IN-G.xml
/prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2013/DirectLoan/CRDL13IN-GCHG.xml
/prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2013/DirectLoan/CRDL13IN-GDISB.xml
/prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2013/DirectLoan/CRDL13IN-U.xml
/prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2013/DirectLoan/CRDL13IN-UCHG.xml
/prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2013/DirectLoan/CRDL13IN-UDISB.xml
/prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2013/Isir/CORR13IN.001
/prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2013/Isir/CORR13IN.002
/prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2013/Isir/CORR13IN.003
/prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2013/Isir/CORR13IN.004
/prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2013/Isir/CORR13IN.005
/prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2013/Isir/CORR13IN.006
/prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2013/Pell/CRPG13IN.xml
/prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2013/Pell/CRPG13IN_DISB.xml
/prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2013/TrnsMonitor/TRNINFIN.01
winDir.: \prd\fa\out\FA003100\SAIG\2012\DirectLoan\
winFile: CRDL12IN-G.xml
mkdir: c:\temp\saig_files\prd\fa\out\FA003100\SAIG\2012\DirectLoan\
Attempting to write: c:\temp\saig_files\prd\fa\out\FA003100\SAIG\2012\DirectLoan\CRDL12IN-G.xml
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (xx,xx,xxx,x,197,16)
RETR /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/DirectLoan/CRDL12IN-G.xml
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/DirectLoan/CRDL12IN-G.xml (4561 bytes).
226 File send OK.
winDir.: \prd\fa\out\FA003100\SAIG\2012\DirectLoan\
winFile: CRDL12IN-GCHG.xml
Attempting to write: c:\temp\saig_files\prd\fa\out\FA003100\SAIG\2012\DirectLoan\CRDL12IN-GCHG.xml
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (xx,xx,xxx,x,197,136)
RETR /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/DirectLoan/CRDL12IN-GCHG.xml
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/DirectLoan/CRDL12IN-GCHG.xml (9074 bytes).
226 File send OK.
winDir.: \prd\fa\out\FA003100\SAIG\2012\DirectLoan\
winFile: CRDL12IN-GDISB.xml
Attempting to write: c:\temp\saig_files\prd\fa\out\FA003100\SAIG\2012\DirectLoan\CRDL12IN-GDISB.xml
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (xx,xx,xxx,x,196,239)
RETR /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/DirectLoan/CRDL12IN-GDISB.xml
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/DirectLoan/CRDL12IN-GDISB.xml (2047 bytes).
226 File send OK.
winDir.: \prd\fa\out\FA003100\SAIG\2012\DirectLoan\
winFile: CRDL12IN-U.xml
Attempting to write: c:\temp\saig_files\prd\fa\out\FA003100\SAIG\2012\DirectLoan\CRDL12IN-U.xml
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (xx,xx,xxx,x,197,137)
RETR /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/DirectLoan/CRDL12IN-U.xml
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/DirectLoan/CRDL12IN-U.xml (3367 bytes).
226 File send OK.
winDir.: \prd\fa\out\FA003100\SAIG\2012\DirectLoan\
winFile: CRDL12IN-UCHG.xml
Attempting to write: c:\temp\saig_files\prd\fa\out\FA003100\SAIG\2012\DirectLoan\CRDL12IN-UCHG.xml
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (xx,xx,xxx,x,196,243)
RETR /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/DirectLoan/CRDL12IN-UCHG.xml
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/DirectLoan/CRDL12IN-UCHG.xml (7503 bytes).
226 File send OK.
winDir.: \prd\fa\out\FA003100\SAIG\2012\DirectLoan\
winFile: CRDL12IN-UDISB.xml
Attempting to write: c:\temp\saig_files\prd\fa\out\FA003100\SAIG\2012\DirectLoan\CRDL12IN-UDISB.xml
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (xx,xx,xxx,x,197,87)
RETR /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/DirectLoan/CRDL12IN-UDISB.xml
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/DirectLoan/CRDL12IN-UDISB.xml (2995 bytes).
226 File send OK.
winDir.: \prd\fa\out\FA003100\SAIG\2012\DirectLoan\
winFile: CRDL12IN.xml
Attempting to write: c:\temp\saig_files\prd\fa\out\FA003100\SAIG\2012\DirectLoan\CRDL12IN.xml
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (xx,xx,xxx,x,196,251)
RETR /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/DirectLoan/CRDL12IN.xml
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/DirectLoan/CRDL12IN.xml (145846 bytes).
226 File send OK.
winDir.: \prd\fa\out\FA003100\SAIG\2012\Pell\
winFile: CRPG12IN.xml
mkdir: c:\temp\saig_files\prd\fa\out\FA003100\SAIG\2012\Pell\
Attempting to write: c:\temp\saig_files\prd\fa\out\FA003100\SAIG\2012\Pell\CRPG12IN.xml
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (xx,xx,xxx,x,197,123)
RETR /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/Pell/CRPG12IN.xml
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/Pell/CRPG12IN.xml (2057 bytes).
226 File send OK.
winDir.: \prd\fa\out\FA003100\SAIG\2012\Pell\
winFile: CRPG12IN_DISB.xml
Attempting to write: c:\temp\saig_files\prd\fa\out\FA003100\SAIG\2012\Pell\CRPG12IN_DISB.xml
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (xx,xx,xxx,x,197,21)
RETR /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/Pell/CRPG12IN_DISB.xml
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/Pell/CRPG12IN_DISB.xml (9709 bytes).
226 File send OK.
winDir.: \prd\fa\out\FA003100\SAIG\2012\TrnsMonitor\
winFile: TRNINFIN.01
mkdir: c:\temp\saig_files\prd\fa\out\FA003100\SAIG\2012\TrnsMonitor\
Attempting to write: c:\temp\saig_files\prd\fa\out\FA003100\SAIG\2012\TrnsMonitor\TRNINFIN.01
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (xx,xx,xxx,x,197,119)
RETR /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/TrnsMonitor/TRNINFIN.01
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/TrnsMonitor/TRNINFIN.01 (453 bytes).
226 File send OK.
winDir.: \prd\fa\out\FA003100\SAIG\2012\TrnsMonitor\
winFile: TRNINFIN.02
Attempting to write: c:\temp\saig_files\prd\fa\out\FA003100\SAIG\2012\TrnsMonitor\TRNINFIN.02
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (xx,xx,xxx,x,197,101)
RETR /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/TrnsMonitor/TRNINFIN.02
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/TrnsMonitor/TRNINFIN.02 (604 bytes).
226 File send OK.
winDir.: \prd\fa\out\FA003100\SAIG\2012\TrnsMonitor\
winFile: TRNINFIN.03
Attempting to write: c:\temp\saig_files\prd\fa\out\FA003100\SAIG\2012\TrnsMonitor\TRNINFIN.03
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (xx,xx,xxx,x,197,109)
RETR /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/TrnsMonitor/TRNINFIN.03
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/TrnsMonitor/TRNINFIN.03 (453 bytes).
226 File send OK.
winDir.: \prd\fa\out\FA003100\SAIG\2012\TrnsMonitor\
winFile: TRNINFIN.04
Attempting to write: c:\temp\saig_files\prd\fa\out\FA003100\SAIG\2012\TrnsMonitor\TRNINFIN.04
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (xx,xx,xxx,x,197,18)
RETR /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/TrnsMonitor/TRNINFIN.04
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/TrnsMonitor/TRNINFIN.04 (453 bytes).
226 File send OK.
winDir.: \prd\fa\out\FA003100\SAIG\2012\TrnsMonitor\
winFile: TRNINFIN.05
Attempting to write: c:\temp\saig_files\prd\fa\out\FA003100\SAIG\2012\TrnsMonitor\TRNINFIN.05
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (xx,xx,xxx,x,197,84)
RETR /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/TrnsMonitor/TRNINFIN.05
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/TrnsMonitor/TRNINFIN.05 (604 bytes).
226 File send OK.
winDir.: \prd\fa\out\FA003100\SAIG\2012\TrnsMonitor\
winFile: TRNINFIN.06
Attempting to write: c:\temp\saig_files\prd\fa\out\FA003100\SAIG\2012\TrnsMonitor\TRNINFIN.06
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (xx,xx,xxx,x,197,70)
RETR /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/TrnsMonitor/TRNINFIN.06
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/TrnsMonitor/TRNINFIN.06 (453 bytes).
226 File send OK.
winDir.: \prd\fa\out\FA003100\SAIG\2012\TrnsMonitor\
winFile: TRNINFIN.07
Attempting to write: c:\temp\saig_files\prd\fa\out\FA003100\SAIG\2012\TrnsMonitor\TRNINFIN.07
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (xx,xx,xxx,x,197,119)
RETR /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/TrnsMonitor/TRNINFIN.07
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/TrnsMonitor/TRNINFIN.07 (3624 bytes).
org.apache.commons.net.io.CopyStreamException: IOException caught while copying.
    at org.apache.commons.net.io.Util.copyStream(Util.java:135)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._retrieveFile(FTPClient.java:1695)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.retrieveFile(FTPClient.java:1669)
    at edu.ohio.saig.SaigFileBuilder.getFiles(SaigFileBuilder.java:196)
    at edu.ohio.saig.SaigFileBuilder.main(SaigFileBuilder.java:63)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.PushbackInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
Logging out...
    at org.apache.commons.net.io.FromNetASCIIInputStream.read(FromNetASCIIInputStream.java:161)
    at org.apache.commons.net.io.FromNetASCIIInputStream.read(FromNetASCIIInputStream.java:139)
    at org.apache.commons.net.io.Util.copyStream(Util.java:101)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    ... 15 more
QUIT
```

Note I can use FileZilla to manually copy the parent directory to the local machine and all of the sub-directories and files are copied automatically.  Here is the log from a FileZilla  session:

```
Status: Resolving address of xxx.xxx.xxx
Status: Connecting to xx.xx.xxx.x:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 (vsFTPd 2.0.5)
Command:    AUTH TLS
Response:   234 Proceed with negotiation.
Status: Initializing TLS...
Status: Verifying certificate...
Command:    USER xxxxx
Status: TLS/SSL connection established.
Response:   331 Please specify the password.
Command:    PASS ************
Response:   230 Login successful.
Command:    OPTS UTF8 ON
Response:   200 Always in UTF8 mode.
Command:    PBSZ 0
Response:   200 PBSZ set to 0.
Command:    PROT P
Response:   200 PROT now Private.
Status: Connected
Status: Sending keep-alive command
Command:    TYPE A
Response:   200 Switching to ASCII mode.
Status: Sending keep-alive command
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2013/TrnsMonitor"
Status: Starting download of /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/TrnsMonitorTRNINFIN.01
Command:    CWD /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012
Status: Starting download of /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/DirectLoan/CRDL12IN.xml
Command:    CWD /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/DirectLoan
Response:   250 Directory successfully changed.
Command:    PASV
Response:   250 Directory successfully changed.
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (xx,xx,xxx,x,197,141)
Command:    RETR TrnsMonitorTRNINFIN.01
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (xx,xx,xxx,x,197,118)
Command:    RETR CRDL12IN.xml
Response:   150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for TrnsMonitorTRNINFIN.01 (3775 bytes).
Response:   150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for CRDL12IN.xml (145846 bytes).
Response:   226 File send OK.
Status: File transfer successful, transferred 3,775 bytes in 1 second
Status: Starting download of /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/DirectLoan/CRDL12IN-UDISB.xml
Command:    CWD /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/DirectLoan
Response:   250 Directory successfully changed.
Command:    TYPE A
Response:   200 Switching to ASCII mode.
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (xx,xx,xxx,x,197,53)
Command:    RETR CRDL12IN-UDISB.xml
Response:   150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for CRDL12IN-UDISB.xml (2995 bytes).
Response:   226 File send OK.
Status: File transfer successful, transferred 145,846 bytes in 1 second
Status: Starting download of /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/DirectLoan/CRDL12IN-UCHG.xml
Command:    PASV
Response:   226 File send OK.
Status: File transfer successful, transferred 2,995 bytes in 1 second
Status: Starting download of /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/DirectLoan/CRDL12IN-U.xml
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (xx,xx,xxx,x,197,123)
Command:    RETR CRDL12IN-UCHG.xml
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (xx,xx,xxx,x,197,51)
Command:    RETR CRDL12IN-U.xml
Response:   150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for CRDL12IN-UCHG.xml (7503 bytes).
Response:   150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for CRDL12IN-U.xml (3367 bytes).
Response:   226 File send OK.
Status: File transfer successful, transferred 3,367 bytes in 1 second
Status: Starting download of /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/DirectLoan/CRDL12IN-GDISB.xml
Command:    PASV
Response:   226 File send OK.
Status: File transfer successful, transferred 7,503 bytes in 1 second
Status: Starting download of /prd/fa/out/FA003100/SAIG/2012/DirectLoan/CRDL12IN-GCHG.xml
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (xx,xx,xxx,x,197,25)
Command:    RETR CRDL12IN-GDISB.xml
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (xx,xx,xxx,x,197,28)
Command:    RETR CRDL12IN-GCHG.xml
Response:   150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for CRDL12IN-GDISB.xml (2047 bytes).
Response:   150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for CRDL12IN-GCHG.xml (9074 bytes).
Response:   226 File send OK.
.
.
.
Status: Disconnected from server
```

Comment: Ok, so I think I have this program working now.  I added some disconnect and connect steps to the getfiles() method (see comments in code snippet below).  I have no idea why this "fixed" the problem though.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found the cause of the error but am unsure how to work around it.  The error is caused when the method retrieveFile() is called multiple times.  It appears to me the method issues a PASV command to the FTP server.  The server responds with a random port number for the client to retrieve the file.  However, the server sometimes reuses a port and when that happens, an exception is thrown when the RETR command is sent.

I am not sure if I need to disconnect and reconnect/login to continue.  I setup a small test within the exception handling to reconnect, but the test is throwing an error javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection.

I'll keep working at it, but any comments/help would be welcome.